# How to access nested data in firestore and save it in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My data in firestore is arranged like this:
[image]

[image]

What I want to archieve is basicly get all "values" out of each doc which I have 3 of this now in the one collection I show in the secound picture. I want to download it only once.
The structure is the following:

chatrooms --> ChatId(1) --> ChatId(2) --> chatmessage

or simpler to understand:

collection --> doc --> collection --> doc

I want to loop through all chattmessages in "ChatId(2)" and get all "value"s out of each "chatmessage" and store them in an array.

I face the difficulty trying to handle such difficult (at least for me) nested calls to firebase and wanted to search for help here. Im working in react-native so Javascript is my language Im using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working on my own, my code looks like this incase you want to replicate it:

```
const loadallmessages = async () => {
        await firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms").doc(`${chatId}`).collection(`${chatId}`).orderBy("timestamp").limit(20).get().then(
            querySnapshot => {
                allChatMessages = [];
                querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    allChatMessages.push(doc.data().value);
                    //console.log("console log inside foreach: ", doc.data().value)
                })
                console.log(allChatMessages)
            })

    };
```

"Limit 20" is limiting my querysnapshot so I just receive 20 messages and because I order by "timestamp" I receive the 20 newest entries only.
As a sidenote, the timestamp entry is something I do in my app itself using basic JS methods inorder to create later, who would have known, a timestamp to show in the chat. Everytime you send a message it gets attached to it and stored with the chatmessage itself. It goes like this:

```
const timestamp = Date.now()
```